# What is the function of away here

Tags: meaning

We just smashed, drank and loved our lives  **away**

I understand the meaning of away in this sentence but is"loved our  lives away" an expression whose purpose is to emphasize that the author at this time spent his life and the one of his girl  only doing that. Would it be the same without away (in this case  does the expression  to love our lives away exist)

Comment: The implication is that they _wasted_ their lives doing those things ('love' being a euphemism for  sex rather than a reference to the emotion, presumably).

Comment: It might allude to the colloquial expression "to [**fritter**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fritter) something away."

Comment: ***I*** don't understand the meaning! I'm okay with *He drank his life away* (his alcohol-related problems meant that his life was "wasted"; he achieved little and/or died young). And just maybe a preoccupation with sex could lead to a wasted life. But what would it mean to ***smash*** your life away?

Comment: Loving one's life away means to be lost in an idle haze of hedonistic sexual pleasure seeking.

Comment: what does it mean " to be lost in an idle haze"

Comment: Its grammatical function is that of complement in the VP coordination "just smashed, drank and loved".